# Daily Site Activity at certain time SEO Impact?

Tags: seo, wordpress

I've Heard that Daily Site Activity at certain time has a Positive SEO Impact; 4 Example if I wanna publish one post a day & I do it every day at 5:00 PM, It makes google understand that I have a daily routine. Is it Right?

And If yes, when I change publish date in wordpress, does it change in the sitemap too? Any Help is appreciated

THX

Comment: These are two different questions. I do not know WP. Google does not give a rip(!) about your schedule or routine. It is *not* a consideration. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well it's natural and a fact that if you update your website everyday with ***new content***, your ranks will go up more than a website which gets updated every month. this does not apply to those websites which copy others content and articles. but as far as I know, the hour and exact time of updating during a day is not relevant because google or other bots are not present on your website every second of the day.